# Error in json parsing while converting response into NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, parsing, jsonp

AM getting below error while converting json response into NSdictionary in json parsing...

ERROR:-JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
    Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 UserInfo=0x4d38270 "Unrecognised leading character"
)

any suggestion...

Comment: We'd need to see the data you're trying to decode

Comment: If you are the one creating the JSON object which your app then parses, then verify if you are creating the JSON object properly. Also as Graham says, paste the data

Comment: +100000 for posting the data.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have the same issue as me... The returning data is in JSONP format instead of pure JSON. In other words you will be dealing with something like

```
functionCall({"Name": "Foo", "Id" : 1234, "Rank": 7});
```

instead of just

```
{"Name": "Foo", "Id" : 1234, "Rank": 7}
```

More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

You'll need to strip the function and parentheses from the string before parsing it through the JSON Framework. You can do that with the following Regular Expression (spaced out to make it easier to see):

```
\w+ \s? \( ( \{ .* \} ) \}
```

And the script to write this is:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\w+\\s?\\((\\{.*\\})\\)"
                         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                           error:&error];

[regex replaceMatchesInString:resultString
                      options:0
                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [resultString length])
                 withTemplate:@"$1"];

NSLog(@"resultString = %@", resultString);
NSLog(@"converted = %@", [resultString JSONValue]);
```

where `resultString` is the response from the url request... It has to be stored as an `NSMutableString` in order for the regex to update it.

Answer (score 0):

actually am not creating the json object by using api am retrieving it..

now i found the reason for that error. am not giving valid json object to covert into nsdictionary...So for getting valid json object we have to produce valid url to retrieve json object.

thanks for your suggestion...